# Problema al iniciar apache2 ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, apache, apache2

me encuentro en PopOs LTS 20-04 LTS (basado en ubuntu), estoy intentando iniciar mi servidor apache2 (https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí],

al ver que está corriendo en el puerto 80, me sale esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Hay alguna manera de ver que está ocasionando este conflicto? Gracias.

Comment: A priori, parece que hay algo que no le gusta en la línea 146 de tu fichero de configuración. De todos modos, échale un vistazo al log, que seguro te arroja mas información. Por defecto, debería estar en /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Comment: También intenta matar todos los  servicios  nuevamente mediante el PID de apache2 y levanta otra  vez la instancia

Comment: Gracias, estuve buscando y encontré la solución en youtube, lo que hice fue reinstalar el apache, pero ahora me surgió otro problema, al cargar el php, veo que no me está funcionando, ya que no se carga la plantilla de info.php, la cual está

Comment: Si tienes ajustes que hacer a tu pregunta, edítala y añade la info relevante. Si tu pregunta se resolvió, marca la respuesta correcta como aceptada o publica tu solución y márcala luego como aceptada

Answer (score -1):

Lo primero es que debes revisar tu configuración:

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

Aparentemente estás con algún problema en lo relacionado a tu instalación de PHP7.2